# Special case of the convergence in mean square: constant random variable - Proof

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'd like to complete the proof of the following proposition: given a succession of random variables $X_n$, with $n = 1, ..., \infty$, and a constant random variable $X = c$ (hypothesis: the expected values and the variances exist), then:

$$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = c \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n] = c \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} Var(X_n) = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Partial proof: I know that (*)

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \big[ (X_n - X)^2 \big] = Var(X_n) + \big( \mathbb{E}[X_n] - X \big)^2
\end{align}
$$

the two terms on the right side are non negative so (the left term is the definition of the convergence in mean square):

$$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left[ (X_n - X)^2 \right] = 0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n \to \infty} Var(X_n) = 0 \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \big( \mathbb{E}[X_n] - X \big)^2 = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

I didn't get how I can get:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = c
$$

and

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_n] = c 
$$

---

EDIT (*) The above result is got by substituting $Y = X_n$ and $c = X$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \big[ (X - c)^2 \big] &= \mathbb{E} \big[ (X - \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[X] - c)^2 \big] = 
 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \Big[ \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big)^2 + \big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big)^2 + 2 \, \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big) \, \big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big) \Big] =
 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \Big[ \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big)^2 \Big] +
\mathbb{E} \Big[ \big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big)^2 \Big] +
\mathbb{E} \Big[ 2 \, \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big) \, \big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big) \Big] =
 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \Big[ \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big)^2 \Big] +
\big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big)^2 +
\mathbb{E} \Big[ 2 \, \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big) \, \big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big) \Big] =
 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \Big[ \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big)^2 \Big] +
\big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big)^2 +
2 \, \big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big) \, \mathbb{E} \big[ X - \mathbb{E}[X] \big] =
 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \Big[ \big(X - \mathbb{E}[X]\big)^2 \Big] +
\big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big)^2 =
 \\
&= Var(X) +
\big( \mathbb{E}[X] - c \big)^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: In what sense does $X_n$ converge to $c$?

Comment: Hello @KaviRamaMurthy in the sense that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left[ (X_n - X)^2 \right] = 0$. This is the definition of convergence in mean square given by my professor

Comment: For who downvoted my question, please specify why

Comment: The question should be self-contained. You talked about mean -square convergence in the title  but not in the question. That caused some confusion and I downvoted but I cannot cancel the downvote unless the question is edited . Please edit the question so that I can upvote it.

Comment: Your first step 'I Know that ...' is wrong.